# Выделение UI кнопки Unity

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-ui

Как в Unity сделать так, чтобы кнопка при одиночном клике слала событие `OnClick`(она по умолчанию это делает и так), а если удерживаешь её более 3х секунд - слала событие `OnSelected`, а при повторном "отжатии" на 3 секунды - слала событие `OnDeseleсted`?

Фактически аналогичный функционал есть у иконок в меню андроида - тыкаешь 1 раз - запускается приложение, жмешь 3 секунды не отпуская - открывается меню удаления или чего либо еще, жмешь на уже выделенную кнопку 3 секунды - состояние сбрасывается на стартовое.

Возможно в UI нет встроенной поддержки такого, тогда может быть, кто то написал велосипед для такого?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь особо ничего сложного нет, вы вполне можете написать свою реализацию, используя интерфейсы IPointerDownHandler и IPointerUpHandler, методы которых вызываются EventSystem при взаимодействие с UI-ем. Если вам нужно прям кнопку расширить, а не дополнительный скрипт сделать - пишите свой класс, наследуйтесь от Button и переопределяйте методы OnPointerDown и OnPointerUp - там совсем всё просто, что-нибудь вроде:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DelayedButton : Button
{
    public UnityEvent OnSelectedEvent = new UnityEvent();

    public UnityEvent OnDeselectedEvent = new UnityEvent();

    [SerializeField]
    float _delay = 3;

    Coroutine _waitRoutine;

    ButtonState _state = ButtonState.Idle;

    public override void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        base.OnPointerDown(eventData);
        _waitRoutine = StartCoroutine(WaitRoutine());
    }

    public override void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (_waitRoutine != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(_waitRoutine);
            _waitRoutine = null;
        }

        if (_state == ButtonState.Selected)
            OnDeselectedEvent?.Invoke();

        _state = ButtonState.Idle;
        base.OnPointerUp(eventData);
    }

    IEnumerator WaitRoutine()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(_delay);
        _state = ButtonState.Selected;
        OnSelectedEvent.Invoke();
        _waitRoutine = null;
    }

    enum ButtonState
    {
        Idle,
        Selected
    }
}
```